# Laravel notification

Tags: laravel, notifications

I already worked with laravel broadcasting and I'm able to send notification to the user connected to my website but i want to know how to send notifications even if the use is not online in the webstie

```
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

var pusher = new Pusher('APP-Key', {
    cluster: 'eu',
    forceTLS: true
});

var channel = pusher.subscribe('news');
channel.bind('News', show());
```

I want to know if there is any way (API or something) to send notification to users devices(mobile, desktop) without required to be connected to the website.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't.

If user isn't on the website then there is no direct or indirect connection - unless you write a phone app or use existing ones.

Comment: but i alerady authenticated to websites that can send to me notification even if wasn't on their website

Comment: @alifilali Like what?

Comment: like this morrocon website https://www.tawjihnet.net/ when you are authenticated they will send to you notification about news without requiring an app

Comment: @alifilali Perhaps it's some Chrome feature? https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/push-notifications/

Comment: is there any other ways because this one look complicated